# How to build Meteor.js in an executable file?

Tags: javascript, meteor, build, electron, exe

I need to build a meteor application under windows. How to do it right?

I found the [meteor-electron](https://github.com/electron-webapps/meteor-electron) package. If I understand correctly, it creates an executable file (exe).

I perform the following commands:

```
meteor create meteor-electron-build-test
cd meteor-electron-build-test
meteor add meson: electron
meteor
```

At this stage, everything is fine, the application of the electron inside the meteor is launched.

But if I stop the electron in the console and go to .meteor-electron \ win32-ia32 \ builds \ Electron-win32-ia32 \ Electron.exe - this application is empty.

I tried to add settings.

```
{
  "electron": {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "A really cool app.",
    "rootUrl": "https://myapp.com",
    "launchPath": "/ app / landing",
    "sign": "Developer ID Application: ...",
    "height": 768,
    "width": 1024,
    "frame": true,
    "title-bar-style": "hidden",
    "resizable": true,
    "protocols": [{
      "name": "MyApp",
      "schemes": ["myapp"]
    }]
  }
}
```

And launched the team meteor --settings settings.json. The result is the same.

https://github.com/StekolschikovV/meteor-electron-build-test

If I add the "appSrcDir" parameter: "./" - starts an endless loop that all copies to the .meteor-electron folder.

How to correctly build an executable file meteor electron using windows?

Answer (score 0):

`meteor-electron` doesn't deliver a meteor server process, only a thin web client. Therefore, your **`rootUrl` setting must point to a valid web address hosting your app.** This can be `http://localhost:3000` for the purposes of testing.

Comment: Can you advise another package or other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try Electrify.  I just tested it on the latest Meteor 1.7 and it works.  Bundles node and MongoDB.  Runs meteor client and server.

```
npm install -g electrify
```

https://github.com/arboleya/electrify